# Executing different commands with separate arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Say that I want to make a script that extracts all tar.gz and tar.bz2 files that are listed as arguments. What I've done so far is something like:

```
if [[ $@ =~ .*"tar.gz".* ]] || [[ $@ =~ .*"tar.bz2".* ]]; then
 for i in $@ =~ .*"tar.gz".*; do
  tar -xvzf "$i"
 done
 for p in $@ =~ .*"tar.bz2".*; do
  tar -xvjf "$p"
 done
else
 echo "tar.gz or tar.bz2 files required."
fi
```

The first line is successful at evaluating whether or not a tar.gz or tar.bz2 file exist, but my problem is the rest. The variables aren't set properly, and the script ends up trying to extract each variable listed with both extraction commands. How can I separate arguments that end with tar.gz and tar.bz2 to perform separate extractions?

Comment: FYI, `[[ $* =~ ... ]]` (running a regex comparison against a *string* created by combining all arguments) is much clearer in terms of its behavior than `[[ $@ =~ ... ]]` (trying to run a regex against an *array*; there's no documented guarantees in terms of what behavior will be in this case, or that it will continue to work in the future at all).

Comment: ...that said, `for i in $@ =~ ...; do` just isn't defined behavior at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably iterate over arguments and test each argument, like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i count
for file in "$@"
do
  if
    [[ $file =~ .*[.]tar[.]gz$ ]]
  then
    tar -xvzf "$file"
  elif
    [[ $file =~ .*[.]tar[.]bz2$ ]]
  then
    tar -xvjf "$file"
  else
    continue
  fi
  count+=1
fi 

((count)) || echo "tar.gz or tar.bz2 files required."
```

If you are OK to rely on GNU `tar` choosing the right decoding algorithm automatically, you can simplify this to :

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i count
for file in "$@"
do
  [[ $file =~ .*[.]tar[.](gz|bz2)$ ]] || continue
  tar -xvf "$file"
  count+=1
fi 

((count)) || echo "tar.gz or tar.bz2 files required."
```

Comment: Need to decide between `z` and `j` based on the type.

Comment: Oops, missed that.  Thanks.

Comment: (Personally, btw, I'm not a fan of `declare -i`, as it's a construct that creates context that has to be known to correctly grok the behavior of code elsewhere in the script -- one can easily read `count+=1` to be a bug that would create `count=11` rather than `count=2` in its absence).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I understand the failure mode you are describing, but is it really worse than using, say, `count=$((count+1))` and having `count` contain a string that would them be converted to an unforeseen integer value other than `0`?  What would you suggest as a replacement?

Comment: if you want best-of-both-worlds, you might do both: `declare -i count`, but then `count=$((count+1))` -- as the latter's behavior can be understood without needing to be aware of the former.

Comment: Pattern matching would be simpler than regex matching here: `[[ $file = *.tar.gz ]]`, etc. The last example (assuming extended pattern matching is enabled) would be `[[ $file = *.tar.@(gz|bz2) ]]`.

Comment: @Charles This would be possible, and would remove the use of `-i` which may not be very well known.  The `count` variable would still need to be declared or initialized (to prevent an exported `count` variable from causing problems).  So I would not say `count=$((count+1))` can be understood fully without reference to any declaration or initialization.

Comment: @chepner Good point.  I do not use pattern matching a lot in my scripts, so I went with what I use most of the time.  This being said, if you need to rely on extended pattern matching to handle both cases in a single statement, you probably end up with more code than the slightly longer regex to handle the option (set it, and potentially restore it afterwards in a case where a later portion of the script might depend on the value not being changed).

Comment: @Fred Starting in 4.1, `extglob` is assumed for the RHS argument to `=`; no need to explicitly turn it on.

Comment: @chepner Do you mean `extglob` is enabled by default, or rather that inside `[[ ]]`, the option is disregarded and the comparison uses extended globbing all the time?  If assumptions regarding the handling of patterns change between version of Bash, I am not sure this would encourage me to use it more...

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any built-in syntax for extracting and iterating over only matching elements of an array, as you're trying to do here.

The below is POSIX-compliant, depending on no bashisms:

```
count=0
for arg; do
  case $arg in
    *.tar.gz)  tar -xvzf "$arg"; count=$(( count + 1 ));;
    *.tar.bz2) tar -xjvf "$arg"; count=$(( count + 1 ));;
  esac
done
if [ "$count" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "tar.gz or tar.bz2 files required" >&2
fi
```

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning, for educational purposes, that under bash you can say `((++count))`

Comment: @ccarton, indeed, I did so in a prior version (apparently within the edit window since I don't see the history link), until deciding to distinguish this answer by making it POSIX-compliant (at which point I also switched from `(( count == 0 ))` to `[ "$count" -eq 0]`).

Answer (score 0):

A bit off-topic, when extracting with GNU tar [it detects the archive type automatically from the file extension](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/suffix.c) since 2007, no need to specify `z|j|J`.

I.e. `tar xvf <filename>`.

Comment: You mean `z|j`. And there's no standard for `tar` (the POSIX-standardized archiver with support for tar-formatted archives is `pax`), so what you're describing here necessarily applies to a very specific implementation, and probably a specific range of versions within that implementation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am describing portable GNU tar, all other tar's are non-portable.

Comment: "All other"? Nonsense. Busybox has a quite portable tar, and I'm almost certain I've seen a ports-style distribution with a BSD tar packaged for multi-OS use, though I'd need to look around to find it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Busybox also auto-detects the archive type from the file magic, so it seems to be portable as well :)))